# How should I use React Router to swap out what I want to display in my header, body and footer?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

From my understanding, React Router is good for when you want to reuse a container and different routes will change what's displayed inside of the container. However, I want it such that a route will change what's displayed in multiple containers.

For example, in my login page, I have my login form in the body container and my link to registration in the footer.

In my registration page, I have my registration form in the body and the link to login in the footer.

In my home page, I have a welcome message in the body and some buttons to change tabs in the footer.

What's the best practice for the component structure involved in this?

Comment: Have you checked React Context? Maybe this could help. For example you can use it for themes. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best practice of `React` is making reused-components that help not to waste your time in coding, just only pick and reuse components in many different scenarios.
 Base on your example, in login page and registration the footer may have the same design but only the links is different. We can create a layout named `LinkInFooter` and receive an array link objects to displayed:

```
  // file /pages/login.js
  <PageLayout>
     <LoginComponent/>
     < LinkInFooter links={[url: '/registration', label: 'registration page']}/>
  </PageLayout>

   // file /pages/registration.js
  <PageLayout>
     <RegistrationComponent/>
     <LinkInFooter links={[url: '/login', label: 'login page']}/>
  </PageLayout>
```

Below is a few tips for you:

- Should have a `WrappedLayout` for all pages, I don't say it should be the same layout for all pages but it should have the same layout for many pages. That `WrappedLayout` will make your page look consistent when change route or hide / show chilren `components`.
- `Layouts/*.js` : Layout directory is the place that hold all your custom small components that you want they are displayed same across your projects. For example: I customized a `Select` component that allow to search item, select multiple items... So that I create an custom `<Select/>` layout to replace html's `<select/>` on my project.
- `Components/*.js`: this one hold all your components, either reusable or non-reusable. A component can be made by compose many others components: what can be reuseable should be created a new file for it and import to use. If not, create an internal component is enough.
- Pay 5 minutes on UI design before start. Use the initial time to imagine the structure of pages then answer these questions :

  - How many component should I have for this pages?
  - Could  be reused frequently?
  - Which items on the design should be `layout`?